# Kerberos gets tickets for wrong user

Tags: windows, authentication, kerberos

At work, I have two active directory/domain accounts:

- `username` - I log in to my computer with this
- `adm_username` - this user is administrator for some servers that I am responsible for

We have a internal web application that uses kerberos/negotiate authentication.

I currently have the following problem:

- When I access the internal web application from any browser, logged in as my normal `username` user, the browser sends the headers indicating that I am `adm_username`.

`klist` output before doing the http request, containing tickets related to me accessing a file share:

```
C:\Users\username>klist

Current LogonId is 0:0x238dad3

Cached Tickets: (3)

#0>     Client: username @ MYDOMAIN.COM
        Server: krbtgt/MYDOMAIN.COM @ MYDOMAIN.COM
        KerbTicket Encryption Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
        Ticket Flags 0x40e00000 -> forwardable renewable initial pre_authent
        Start Time: 1/7/2021 9:27:13 (local)
        End Time:   1/7/2021 19:27:13 (local)
        Renew Time: 1/14/2021 9:27:13 (local)
        Session Key Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
        Cache Flags: 0x1 -> PRIMARY
        Kdc Called: NOOSLDC01.mydomain.com

#1>     Client: username @ MYDOMAIN.COM
        Server: cifs/RKNWVDFS002P.mydomain.com @ MYDOMAIN.COM
        KerbTicket Encryption Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
        Ticket Flags 0x40a00000 -> forwardable renewable pre_authent
        Start Time: 1/7/2021 9:27:13 (local)
        End Time:   1/7/2021 19:27:13 (local)
        Renew Time: 1/14/2021 9:27:13 (local)
        Session Key Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
        Cache Flags: 0
        Kdc Called: NOOSLDC01.mydomain.com

#2>     Client: username @ MYDOMAIN.COM
        Server: cifs/NOOSLDC01.mydomain.com @ MYDOMAIN.COM
        KerbTicket Encryption Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
        Ticket Flags 0x40a40000 -> forwardable renewable pre_authent ok_as_delegate
        Start Time: 1/7/2021 9:27:13 (local)
        End Time:   1/7/2021 19:27:13 (local)
        Renew Time: 1/14/2021 9:27:13 (local)
        Session Key Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
        Cache Flags: 0
        Kdc Called: NOOSLDC01.mydomain.com
```

I then use a browser to access the internal website, and execute `klist` again, I now have two extra tickets:

```
#3> Client: adm_username @ mydomain.COM
    Server: krbtgt/mydomain.COM @ mydomain.COM
    KerbTicket Encryption Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
    Ticket Flags 0x40e00000 -> forwardable renewable initial pre_authent 
    Start Time: 1/7/2021 9:37:20 (local)
    End Time:   1/7/2021 19:37:20 (local)
    Renew Time: 1/14/2021 9:37:20 (local)
    Session Key Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
    Cache Flags: 0x1 -> PRIMARY 
    Kdc Called: NOOSLDC01

#4> Client: adm_username @ mydomain.COM
    Server: HTTP/rknwveva001p.mydomain.com @ mydomain.COM
    KerbTicket Encryption Type: RSADSI RC4-HMAC(NT)
    Ticket Flags 0x40a00000 -> forwardable renewable pre_authent 
    Start Time: 1/7/2021 9:37:20 (local)
    End Time:   1/7/2021 19:37:20 (local)
    Renew Time: 1/14/2021 9:37:20 (local)
    Session Key Type: RSADSI RC4-HMAC(NT)
    Cache Flags: 0 
    Kdc Called: NOOSLDC01.mydomain.com
```

Notice that I get tickets for `adm_username` not `username` as expected.

Misc info:

- This happens even after I reboot.
- It has never happened before. On the day this started happening, I had accessed some UNC paths using `adm_username` (by doing `net use \\server\share /user:MYDOMAIN\adm_username`). That is the only uncommon thing I did that I can think of, and is what I suspect is related to this.
- **update**: The same thing happens (only I get cifs tickets instead of http) if I do a `dir \\servername\c$` so it seems that Windows somehow caches information from the previous `net use`

Questions:

- What can be the cause of this? Is it likely a problem on the client side or on the AD/server side?
- How to fix?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my problem was to use Control Panel | User Accounts | Credential Manager, and selecting 'Remove' for the Windows Credential for the server/username combination.

The internal web application is served from one of the servers where I had accessed a file share using `adm_username`, and the Windows kerberos system then tells the browser to use this username when accessing the web server.

This seems to be the root cause for my problem.

Comment: Did you find a solution to make browser use the correct active WindowsUI session user?